# Log execution time of each statement in classic ASP file

Tags: asp-classic

I am dealing with a horrible set of classic ASP files with no existing logging/auditing capabilities.

I desperately need to identify performance bottlenecks in the code but there are too many places to log in the code.

Even worse, due to the way the site is structured (it depends on other sites and a particular instance of an application), I cannot debug the site.

**Is there any way to audit the time elapsed between each execution step (ie Step Over) in the execution of the ASP interpreter?**

Answer (score 0):

1. create own ActiveX component with following method: GetTickCount and QueryPerformanceCounter (much better to use QueryPerformanceCounter). or you could try to found any 3rd party ActiveX component that have such methods.
2. register own/3rd ActiveX component.
3. use it on your own pages....

http://1click.lv/d/ZPerfCounter.dll (Powered on Delphi 7)

MD5 = 45c74aa9f4f6f1384d48e2232f37baf3

works fine with IIS7 (Windows 7 -- 64bit)

:)

following DLL contain only 2 functions:

```
long _stdcall doGetTickCount(void);
unsigned __int64 _stdcall doQueryPerformanceCounter(void);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question, I think, can be paraphrased to

`Does ASP.DLL have any extension points to tap into to measure performance?`

And I think the answer is no.

But it is very likely that the performance issues you were seeing come from external interactions like database, external resources, I/O. the following tools may help:
- Perfmon ASP counters
- Database profiling, like SQL Server Profiler
- browser-based profilers (Fiddler or dev tools' Network panels)